# Existence of finitely presented group with exactly $k$ subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, markov-process

Given any natural number $k$, does there necessarily exist a finitely presented group $G$ with $k$ subgroups? I'm trying to show that having $k$ subgroups is a markov property, but google doesn't seem to yield much on this matter.

Comment: Any infinite group has infinitely many subgroups. So this is just a question about finite groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you didn't say non-Abelian, I snipe the cheepo: 
$\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k-1}}$ for any prime $p$ has exactly $k$ subgroups, as $p^{k-1}$ has exactly $k$ divisors.

Comment: I guess it's not $\Bbb Z_p^{k-1}$, but rather $\Bbb Z/(p^{k-1})$.

Answer (score 2):

We can even take a finite abelian group, namely the cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}/p^{k-1}$. This site also has the question to find a non-abelian group with exactly $k$ *normal* subgroups.

Reference: [Non-abelian finite groups with exactly $n$ normal subgroups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683345/non-abelian-finite-groups-with-exactly-n-normal-subgroups)

Comment: I don't understand the reference to $(\Bbb{Z}/p)^k$ here. Are you claiming that $(\Bbb{Z}/p)^k$ has exactly $k$ subgroups? I'd expect it to have many more than that: there should be $(p^k-1)/(p-1)$ subgroups of order $p$ for a start.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Sorry, it should be the cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}/n$ for appropriate $n$.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: The notation varies. I denite the cyclic group by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or sometimes $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$. I am aware that the notations $Z_n$ and $C_n$ are also used. Makes no difference, right?

Comment: @A.Pongrácz Right. With $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is more confusion, since this is also the ring of $p$-adic integers, and $\Bbb{Z}_p^k$ the direct product of it with $k$ factors.

Comment: You are right, I should stick to $Z_p$. But I am a teacher, and for the sake of my students, I prefer to indicate the operation, as well. Anyway, the safest option is $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, +)$, but it is too long... I see that I put the exponent to the wrong place, to create even more confusion. Fixed now.